# Eclipse Neon Tern on Ubuntu 16.04 javascript context assist only works after saving file

Tags: javascript, ubuntu-16.04, content-assist, eclipse-neon, tern

I have a javascript project converted to a tern project. Content assist was working fine until very recently.
Now if I Ctrl-Space it still brings up the correct choices but when I press enter the screen scrolls downwards just past my current line and the entry is not entered.
It only works if I save the file before EVERY content assist attempt.
It's a right pain in the rear-end I can say?
Does anybody have any ideas what may have gone wrong?
I have tried cleaning and restarting eclipse but no good.